# How to "delete and remove" (not "delete and archive") with Mailchimp's API v3?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

The [mailchimp API docs](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/) has so much to say about deleting addresses:

> If you want to delete an address anyway, along with all its
>   statistics, make a DELETE call to that address’s endpoint.

But there are 2 ways to delete addresses with MailChimp; you can either "delete and remove" or "delete and archive". (more on that in the [non-api docs](https://mailchimp.com/help/delete-contacts/))

I want to delete and remove from the API, but it looks like the API's delete call only does delete and archive.

How can we specify a delete method from the API?

Also, am I right when I say that the API does "delete and archive" by default?

I'm using the mailchimp-api-v3 npm package, a simplified version of my code is below.

```
let allTheRequest = []

mailchimp.get({ path: '/search-members?query=' + "if_you_match_this_I_delete_you"}, function(err, data) {

    data.full_search.members.forEach(function (value) {

        allTheRequest.push({
            method:"delete", 
            path: '/lists/' + value.list_id + '/members/' + crypto.createHash('md5').update(value.email_address).digest('hex'),}
            )
    })

    mailchimp.batch(allTheRequest, function (err, results) {
        console.log('@results: ', results);
        // It all works, we get down here.
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the way to permanently delete an address is to use a POST with the following path:

```
/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}/actions/delete-permanent
```

Here is the link to the docs:

https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#%20

Click on "Action", next to "Delete".

Comment: The URL has for the API is now (otherwise accurate)

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/